# What is the purpose of the two diodes in the output stage at the right in following figure

Tags: electric-circuits, experimental-physics

[image]

as shown, in my option one diode looks enough, is there any special reason we have to connect two of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This circuit stage is a [class AB amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_amplifier_classes#Class_AB). The voltage drop across each base-emitter junction is the same as across one forward-biased diode, so two diodes are needed to match the drop across two transistor B-E junctions. This biases both transistors slightly on.

For a small signal, they each operate as a Class A amplifier, in which the transistor output is always on. But at higher currents this can dissipate a lot of power.

So for a strong signal each transistor becomes reverse biased, i.e. switched off, for half the signal while the other transistor is on. Every time the waveform changes sign (up to 40,000 times a second in HiFi audio), the transistors swap over. This is class B operation. But for low signals, in a pure Class B setup the crossover point introduces audible distortion.

A single-transistor amplifier in Class A mode operates close to the midpoint on (the linear portion of) its output curve. The maximum power theorem means that it is dissipating maximum power when there is no signal. So Class AB was developed to avoid the worst problems with each of the others.

Comment: As a renowned audio amplifier designer used to say: "Class A is good for cooking"!